# Does anyone have a working example of using Qt to communicate with NXT?

Tags: nxt, troubleshooting

I'm stumped. I've been looking through all of the Qt classes and I'm so completely and utterly lost. There are only three examples of bluetooth use in Qt, but none of them work for me. I just need a program that can talk with NXT and analyze an image from a webcam.

Has anybody gotten this to work before?

Comment: Check this [similar question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4937/can-i-use-qt-to-communicate-with-a-lego-nxt-robot)

Comment: After a lot of trial and error and messing around for another 6 hours, I found that there was something wrong with the bluetooth stack. I have it working now only with Matlab. The person who answered said it was possible, but doesn't have a working example. Do you have a working example?